# Combining images of different opacities in Python?

Tags: python, image, opacity, image-segmentation

I want to write a Python program that predicts which state a user is typing and highlights the predicted cities on a map. For example, if the user types "New" and hits the predict button, the program should highlight the following cities: New York, New Mexico, New Jersey, and New Hampshire. Highlighting cities should be done by changing opacities.

My idea is to have one image for each state, then putting them together with different opacities by changing the alpha channel and showing the results to the user.

The following code is what I've done so far for mixing images with different opacities, but I think it won't be a good solution and There must be a better way to do this (or maybe not).

Is there any way to segment a map and change the opacity of each segment separately? If not, what might be a better solution? Can you give me sample code?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas
import ImageTk
import Image

#create a mixed images
handle = Image.open("C:\images\1.jpg")##  first image (first state)
handle.putalpha(50)
handle.save("bv.png")
df=Image.open("bv.png")
dd =Image.open("C:\images\2.jpg") ##  second image (second state)
df.paste(dd,(100,200))


#show the mixed image
t = Tk()
frame = Frame(t)
frame.pack()
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=1024, height=768)
canvas.pack()
photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(df)
canvas.create_image(512, 384, image=photoimage)
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: New Hampshire, New Mexico, and New Jersey aren't cities... do you want the program to highlight *states*, or [only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Mexico,_Maryland) [cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Hampshire,_Ohio)?

Comment: Then edit your question to say states instead of cities...

Comment: Use 50 different images same size as the background with only the individual states in them (transparent otherwise). Paste these on top of the master image.